# Add default ngModelAttrs for all types

Tags: angular-formly

When declaring a field, I can specify `ngModelAttrs` for that field such as:

```
{
  key: 'confirmName',
  name: 'confirmName',
  type: 'input',
  templateOptions: {
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Confirm Name',
    equalsValidationMessage: 'Does not match name'
  },
  ngModelAttrs: {
    equals: {attribute: 'equals'}
  },
  expressionProperties: {
    'templateOptions.equals': 'model.name'
  }
}
```

I would like to add `equals` to the list of standard model attributes, in the same way that `min`, `max`, `minlength`, etc are standard.

Comment: Depending on how the `equals ` attribute directive works, you may need to specify `bound ` rather than `attribute `. If you could create an example that would be the most helpful: http://help.angular-formly.com

Comment: The `equals` directive is declared using `attrs.$observe` similar to the `maxlength` directive. Working example http://embed.plnkr.co/LpKkj2/preview

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a single field working, you're just looking at how to create a reusable `type` so you don't have to repeat yourself. Take a look at this example: http://angular-formly.com/#/example/custom-types/default-options

Basically you define a type with `formlyConfig` that has `defaultOptions`

Comment: How do I define default options on an existing type such as input when using formly bootstrap? Ideally I'd like it to apply to any type so that it will work on both inputs and selects.

Comment: Two ways to do that depending on how you want it done. Use `extends` or `optionsTypes`